# how to minimize and restore the magnifier utility (autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

the two windows that are created when you turn on the magnifier utility of windows10 is

1. ahk_class MagUIClass
2. WinRestore ahk_class Screen Magnifier Window

what I want to do is minimize and restore the two windows with keyboard shortcuts

```
1::
    Click, 4500, 150, 0
    WinMinimize ahk_class Screen Magnifier Window
    WinMinimize ahk_class MagUIClass
    return 

2::
    Click, 3000, 150, 0
    WinRestore ahk_class Screen Magnifier Window
    WinRestore ahk_class MagUIClass
    return
```

but for some reason, this doesn't seem to work

what I want to do is hide and unhide the magnifier window quickly.
I have tried closing and opening the magnifier, but opening it takes a lot of time (that is why I am now trying to minimize and restoring it)

Answer (score 0):

ended up using a magnifier made completely in AutoHotkey.

source:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/10660-screenmagnifier/

the only problem with this is that it doesn't replicate the mouse
(really need the mouse to be displayed)

this script can easily be minimized and restored by hiding and unhiding the gui

Edit: ok so can't use it without mouse so this option is not good